# Trying to call static function in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to call a static function from a class but the intellisense is not picking it up?

the function return

```
 public static ArrayList GetInfo(int infoID)
```

and i am calling from somewhere else in another class, I was trying to do something like

```
var myitem = myClassName.GetInfo(x);
```

but intelisense doesnt pick it up... as I type myClassName.

How can i call it? if at all possible

PS: I cant change the signature of the method :(.

Comment: Does this happen in every single version of Visual Studio? I assume so because you didn't say which version you are using.

Comment: could you add some more code to your question? The context may be important here..

Comment: Make sure your class is public or otherwise accessible from where you trying to use.

Comment: Perhaps you're calling it from a different project and forgot to add a reference?

Comment: Are the calling class and the class containing the static method in the same namespace?

Comment: Does the code compile? It should be accessible as @Bala R mentions, if it's in another namespace, make sure you're `using` it, and if it's in another assembly make sure you reference it as @sheldon says.

Comment: no that doesnt compile i was just trying to show what i was trying to do, but i see how it is now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally you do have a `namespace` as well, plus that static method has to be inside it's own class, for example, something like:

```
namespace MyHelpers {

    public static class ArrayHelpers {

        public static ArrayList GetInfo(int infoID) { ... }
    }
}
```

now, no matter where you are in your application, and if that library is referenced to your current project you simply call it

```
ArrayList myitem = MyHelpers.ArrayHelpers.GetInfo(x);
```

remember that you need to give the full path and if your namespace is called `namespace Model.Helpers { ...`

then the full path will be:

```
ArrayList myitem = Model.Helpers.ArrayHelpers.GetInfo(x);
```

is you are using the `using` declaration

```
using Model.Helpers;
```

you can use

```
ArrayList myitem = ArrayHelpers.GetInfo(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Static functions cant be accessed with variable name, but with class name. So basicly just call either just `GetInfo(int)` ( if you want to call it within the class where the GetInfo() is ) or `YourClass.GetInfo(int)` ( outside the class where GetInfo() is ).

If you are calling outside the class, make sure that you are using same namespace in both, or you are using appropriate `using` statements.

Comment: `myClassName` looks like a class name. If it was an instance then the code would not compile.

Comment: @David Oh.. I somehow thought it was variable since it started with lower case character :|

Comment: Yes sorry myClassName is the class name

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the class in a subfolder of your project? If so, you need to call it like this:

```
subfolder.myclassname.getinfo()
```